# Relationship between total support and fully indecomposability.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

I have to prove that if a nonnegative matrix $A$ has total support then there exist $P,Q$ permutation matrix such that $$PAQ=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k A_i$$ where $A_i$ is fully indecomposable $\forall i=1,\dots, k$ and the $\bigoplus$ symbol means "direct sum" of matrices.

I found many reference on this theorem but no one is complete.

Could you help me?

Some papers I found cite [image: this theorem] , but I cannot find a link between the two ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a non-negative $n\times n$ matrix.

If $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ then the entries $a_{1\sigma(1)},\ldots,a_{n,\sigma(n)}$ are called a diagonal of $A$.

A diagonal of $A$ is positive if it does not contain any zero entry.

A non-negative matrix $A$ has total support if every $a_{ij}\neq0$ belongs to some positive diagonal of A.

So $A$ does not have total support if and only if there is $a_{ij}\neq0$ such that the submatrix obtained by deleting row $i$ and column $j$ has no positive diagonal.

[Frobenius-König theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Frobenius-KoenigTheorem.html) says that $A$ does not contain a positive diagonal (its permanent is zero) if and only if there is a submatrix of A occupying s rows and t columns, which is identically zero, such that $s+t>n$.

Now, assume that $A$ is not fully indecomposable, but has total support. Then there are permutation matrices $P,Q$ such that $PAQ=\begin{pmatrix}X_{s\times s} &Y_{s\times n-s}\\
0_{n-s\times s}&Z_{n-s\times n-s}\end{pmatrix}$.

If $Y_{ij}\neq 0$ then deleting its row and column we obtain a submatrix $M$ of $PAQ$ of order $n-1$. Notice that $O_{n-s\times s}$ still is a submatrix of $M$ and $n-s+s=n>n-1$. Hence, $M$ does not contain a positive diagonal and $PAQ$ does not have total support. Absurd! So $Y_{s\times n-s}$ must be identically zero.

Now, use induction on $X$ and $Z$.

Comment: Yes, it's clear what you writed. Just a remark: Frobenius-König theorem you cited deals with 0-1 matrices. Can It be extended to the general nonnegative case?

Comment: Hi @aleio1. Yes. We can extend this theorem to non-negative matrices. Actually, this is how the theorem is stated here (https://www.amazon.com/Survey-Matrix-Theory-Inequalities-Mathematics/dp/048667102X). Do you agree that this problem has nothing to do with the values of the entries of A? Replace each positive entry of A by 1. Find the required permutation matrices P,Q. Then put the original entries back on A. Best Regards.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. I'm dealing also with the converse of the statement above, i.e. proving that if A is direct sum of fully indecomposable matrices it follows that A cannot be permuted in the form (*). Do you have any hint?

Comment: Hi @aleio1. The converse of the statement should be - If there are permutations $P,Q$ such that $ PAQ$ is a direct sum o fully indecomposable maps then A has total support, right?

Comment: @aleio1 Notice that $PAQ$ and $A$ share the same positive diagonals but in different positions. So A has total support if and only if $PAQ$ has total support. We reduced the problem to prove that a direct sum o fully indecomposable matrices has total support. Notice that, we just need to prove that each matrix in this direct sum has total support. Thus, we reduced the problem once again. We must show that every fully  indecomposable matrix has total support.

Comment: @aleio If A does not have total support then there is $a_{ij}\neq 0$ not cointaned in any positive diagonal of $A$. So if we remove row $i$ and column $j$ from $A$, we get a matrix B with no positive diagonal. Then Frobenius-Konig theorem says that there is a identically zero submatrix of $B$ occupying $n-s$ rows and $s$ columns. Notice that this submatrix of $B$ is also a submatrix of  $A$. Now, permute the rows and columns of $A$ in order to put this identically zero submatrix in the required position. So $A$ is not fully indecomposable.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. The statement that I meant is the following: suppose A is a direct sum of fully indecomposable matrices, then it cannot be permuted in the form (*) (see image I posted above). 
I proceded as follow:

Comment: I can suppose that fully indecomposable blocks of A are ordered such that the rows of the first $s$ blocks contain the entries belonging to the upper part of $PAQ$. $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 \\
& A_2  \\
& & \ddots \\
& & & A_s \\
& & & & A_{s+1}\\
& & & & & \ddots \\
& & & & & &A_t
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: No entries of the square matrix formed by the first $s$ blocks can contain zero entries from the zero block of $PAQ$ otherwise the column relative to this zero entries would be entirely zero and this would contradict the fully indecomposability of diagonal blocks of A.
It follows that up to row permutation of the lower part of A, the rows of the last $n-s$ rows of A are the same of the $[Y,Z]$ part of $PAQ$ and this would imply that $Y=0$

Comment: @aleio I understood now. As I said, in the comments above, a direct sum of fully indecomposable matrices has total support (Check my last three comments). If the matrix could be permuted in the form $(*)$ then there is $Y_{ij}\neq 0$. After deleting row i and column j, we would have an identically zero submatrix of order $k \times n-k$. So by Frobenius-Konig this submatrix has no positive diagonal. So there is no positive diagonal containing $Y_{ij}\neq 0$. Thus, the matrix has no total support. absurd! So the matrix can not be permuted in $(*)$.

Comment: Thank you once again @Daniel. Is it my proof correct too?

Comment: surely your proof is more elegant than mine. Could anyway tell me if my one is wrong?

Comment: Hi @aleio1. I apologize for my late reply. I can not tell you if your proof is right.  Perhaps you should ask a new question. Regards.